# grails fixtures refresh()ing error with neo4j

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-2.3

I am trying to load some data via Bootstrap.groovy in to a neo4j db using neo4j plugin.

I am using grails 2.3.8, neo4j 2.0.0-M01 & fixtures 1.2.7

## The data is loaded successfully but I am getting the following error

Error |
2014-05-12 03:39:25,442 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error refresh()ing bean 'hilton'
Message: Error refresh()ing bean 'hilton'
    Line | Method
->>  154 | createApplicationContext         in grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder

---

|     54 | load                             in grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader
|     50 | load . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture
|     38 | load                             in grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader
|      7 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
|    308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    301 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Can someone help explain what this means?

## Update: Full Stacktrace

2014-05-14 08:22:19,333 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
grails.plugin.fixtures.exception.FixtureException: Error refresh()ing bean 'hilton'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:986)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.createApplicationContext(FixtureBuilder.groovy:154)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder$createApplicationContext$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader.load(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.load(Fixture.groovy:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.doLoad(FixtureLoader.groovy:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.load(FixtureLoader.groovy:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:960)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
.................
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jEntityPersister.refresh(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:382)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.refresh(AbstractSession.java:547)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi$_refresh_closure3.doCall(GormInstanceApi.groovy:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.doInSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.refresh(GormInstanceApi.groovy:89)
    at leverpoc2.HotelChain.refresh(HotelChain.groovy)

Comment: could you check if `target/stacktrace.log` contains a full stacktrace? If so, paste it here.

Comment: updated with full stacktrace...hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is an issue with neo4j-grails with neo4j post 2.0.  Currently the plugin is being refactored and developed to fix this problem.  Stay tuned for more updates!

Answer (score 0):

the refresh method on domain classes is not yet supported in the Neo4j plugin. Could you please file a ticket at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues